# Как правильно реализовать удаление категории и перемещение привязанных постов в основную?

Tags: laravel

Есть какое-то количество категорий (файл миграции категорий)

```
public function up():void
{
    Schema::create('blog_categories', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(1);

        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

Среди них есть "базовая"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все эти категории привязаны к постам (файл миграции постов)

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('blog_posts', static function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();

        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('excerpt')->nullable();

        $table->string('tdk_title')->nullable();
        $table->text('tdk_description')->nullable();
        $table->text('tdk_keywords')->nullable();

        $table->text('content_raw');
        $table->text('content_html');

        $table->integer('view_count')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('is_published')->default(false);
        $table->timestamp('published_at')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->index('is_published');

        //FK
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('blog_categories')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Нужно решить две задачи:

1. **Запретить удаление корневой категории**. С этим проблем нет, в destroy() проверить id и если он совпадает вернуть сообщение с ошибкой.
2. **Удалить категорию и переместить все связанные посты в корневую**. Вот тут я забуксовал, как правильно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я сделал бы следующим образом:
1 в модели описал бы связь:

```
/**
 * @return HasMany
 */
public function posts(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
```

2 при удалении директории получил бы все ее посты:

```
$posts = $category->posts;
```

3 ну и обновил бы каждый пост. А затем удалил категорию.

```
if ( $posts->count() ) {
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        // update $post
    }
}

$category->delete();
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @yaleksandr89: был рад помочь))

Comment: небольшое уточнение, косвенно связанное темой, но ответ на который не смог нагуглить. 

Можно ли в destroy передать дополнительную переменную? Поясню, хочу в форме редактирования добавить переключатель с возможностью выбора - удалить связанные посты или переместить в корневую категорию. Соответственно в методе destroy нужно как-т проверить, какой вариант был выбран.

Comment: @yaleksandr89: хм...)) не думаю, но попробовать можно.. хотя я, наверное, сделал бы две кнопки, две формы, два роута и два метода. Один метод перемещает посты и вызывает destroy(); второй - удаляет и тоже вызывает destroy().

Comment: тоже рассматривал такой вариант =), просто думал обойтись методами ресурсного контроллера. Но в целом согласен с вами, быстрее сделать два маршрута.

UPD: уже хотел отправить, но решил попробовать вариант и сработал
` {{ route('limbo.blog.categories.destroy', [$category->id, 'title' => $category->title]) }} `
Главное первым передать id, а дальше можно пихнуть те данные, которые нужны и в самом destroy вызывать хелпер request()->all() :)

Comment: @yaleksandr89: прикольно)). Но насколько правильно отправлять данные методом DELETE? насколько это кошерно и не выпилят ли эту "возможность" в ближайшем будущем? я не утверждаю, а задаюсь вопросом.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, да и посмотрев на сам стиль - пахнуло говнокодом =). Решил сделать, как вы посоветовали, в роутах завести отдельный маршрут для удаления и перемещения в корневую, а над destroy более не издеваться)))